# Remotebuild 'Unexpected end of input' when running iOS Cordova app

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, taco

When I try to run my Cordova app from Visual Studio 2015 on a Mac with remotebuild installed, I always get this in the Output window:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Holmwoods.Cordova, Configuration: Debug iOS ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 4.2.2 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.28
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 5.4.1 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    <<snip>>
1>  ------ Adding platform: ios
1>MDAVSCLI : warning : Applications for platform ios can not be built on this OS - win32.
1> <<snip>>
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It looks to me like it's trying to build and run the iOS app from Windows, even though I have configured the remotebuild agent under Tools > Options.

On the Mac, I don't see any requests coming in during build. I do see a GET request in the Terminal when I reconfigure the remote build agent in Visual Studio.

Comment: you find a solution to this?

Comment: I will try it soon with the updated tools. Now I simply have the repository cloned on the mac and build and debug straight from there, which works fine.

Comment: It works again with the latest Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova (Update 8).

Comment: Are you still having this issue? I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova team at Microsoft. Right now, we're investigating ways to make it easier for developers to recover from remote build errors in VS. It would be great to chat with you about this issue. Customer feedback is the number one way we make product design decisions, so I’d love it if you could make time for a 20min phone call this week or next to talk about how you understand and overcome build issues. jomatthi [at] Microsoft [dot] com

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem

What i did to fix it was create a blank new project and compare the confix.xml files.

The other thing I did was to remove everything in my plugins folder and re-add the plugins using the visual studio GUI for config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to write cammand prompt of your project file

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```

android or your platform..